# How to add a delay after getting the list before starting the loop in the shell script

Tags: file, unix

Below script list, the files, change the permissions on the file and moving it to a different folder. Sometimes the script is moving the file before the contents fully generated.

Need to add a delay after getting the list before starting the loop. Is this possible? Please help how to achieve this scenario to implement.

Can we use the `sleep` command to achieve this?

Script to change the file permissions and move it to main folder

#### function starts here

```
function mv_purge_files
{
  cd $SRC

  if  [ "$?" = "0" ]; then

    for c in $(/usr/bin/ls *)
    do
       echo "ext: changing file permission $c"
       /usr/bin/chmod 775 $c

       echo "ext: moving $c"
       /usr/bin/mv $c $TGT/$c
    done
  else
    echo "Error accessing folder " $SRC
  fi
}
```

#### program starts here

```
SRC=/temp/file.in
TGT=/tgt/purge

mv_purge_files
```

Comment: When will the files be completed? After 2 seconds sleep? Or when no changes have been made during the last 1 minute? Of after the line "Closed " ?

Comment: Hi Walter,Once the files available need to wait/sleep for 1 minute and then execute the For loop ..

Comment: @etlinfa: When you write "*moving the file before the contents fully generated*" do you mean that the list of files you are building with the `ls` are being generated in the `$SRC` directory when you do the `ls` or are they already there and complete ?

Comment: Hi mszmurlo, Thank you for reply. Sometimes files being generated in the $SRC directory before  moving those files.to avoid that need to add delay/sleep for the files before moving. Appreciate your quick help

Comment: You can use `sleep 60`, maybe you only want this one time in your loop.
You will have problems with special filenames (including spaces or newlines), perhaps you want to change your solution to something with `find`. Check the options on your `find`, you might want something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1`.